# Inserir valor da Checkbox no banco e depois usá-lo na tela

Tags: android, sqlite, checkbox

Tenho uma tela de cadastro de receita que contém um Checkbox chamado "recebido", gostaria de saber como faço pra inserir no sqlite uma tinyint e depois resgatar quando eu quiser consultar essa receita. Ex : Eu crio uma receita e deixo o check recebido vazio, salvo essa receita e quando eu for consultar pra poder editar, esse checkbox vir vazio, ou então o contrário, se eu inserir com check recebido ligado, quando for editar ele vir ligado.

Classe Receita

```
public class Receita {
private Float valor;
private String data;
private String descricao;
private boolean recebido;
private int idGrupo;
private int idSubgrupo;
private int idUsuario;
private boolean sincronizado;
private Date incluidoEm;
private int id;


public Float getValor() {
    return valor;
}

public void setValor(Float valor) {
    this.valor = valor;
}

public String getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}

public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
}

public boolean isRecebido() {
    return recebido;
}

public void setRecebido(boolean recebido) {
    this.recebido = recebido;
}

public int getIdGrupo() {
    return idGrupo;
}

public void setIdGrupo(int idGrupo) {
    this.idGrupo = idGrupo;
}

public int getIdSubgrupo() {
    return idSubgrupo;
}

public void setIdSubgrupo(int idSubgrupo) {
    this.idSubgrupo = idSubgrupo;
}

public int getIdUsuario() {
    return idUsuario;
}

public void setIdUsuario(int idUsuario) {
    this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
}

public boolean isSincronizado() {
    return sincronizado;
}

public void setSincronizado(boolean sincronizado) {
    this.sincronizado = sincronizado;
}

public Date getIncluidoEm() {
    return new Date();
}

public void setIncluidoEm(Date incluidoEm) {
    this.incluidoEm = incluidoEm;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

Método que busca do banco

```
public Receita passarTela(int id) {
    Receita receita = new Receita();
    Cursor c = getWritableDatabase().query(TABELA, COLUNAS, " _id = " + id, null, null, null, null);

    while (c.moveToNext()){
        String[] aux = c.getString(1).split("-");


        receita.setValor(c.getFloat(0));
        receita.setData(aux[2] + "/" + aux[1] + "/" + aux[0]);
        receita.setDescricao(c.getString(2));
        receita.setRecebido(c.getString(3).equalsIgnoreCase("0"));
        receita.setIdSubgrupo(c.getInt(4));
        receita.setId(c.getInt(8));



    }
    c.close();
    return receita;
}
```

Método que insere no banco

```
    public void inserir(Receita receita) {
    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put("valor", receita.getValor());
    valores.put("data", receita.getData());
    valores.put("descricao", receita.getDescricao());
    valores.put("recebido", receita.isRecebido());
    valores.put("idsubgrupo", receita.getIdSubgrupo());
    valores.put("incluidoem", receita.getIncluidoEm().toString());
    valores.put("sincronizado", receita.isSincronizado());

    getWritableDatabase().insert(TABELA, null, valores);
}
```

Comment: Allan Chrystian, você tem que aprender que por mais que você ache que não precisa apresentar os seus códigos, você precisa apresentar.

Comment: @Lollipop eu sei que preciso, só não sei quais preciso apresentar, mas vou editar o que tenho aqui. Obrigado

Comment: O seu código irá nos mostrar o que você já tem.

Comment: editado @Lollipop

Comment: A sua pergunta é ampla demais. Existem muitas etapas para se alcançar esta resposta. Você tem que primeiro tentar buscar algo no google, estudar e vir aqui perguntar algo mais específico, exemplo: Você tentou criar uma checkbox e tentou inserir os seus valores no banco, mas está dando erro. Você vem aqui e pergunta: **Dados da checkbox não insere no SQLiter**. Apresenta seus códigos,  explica as etapas que alcançou.

Comment: Ok, vou dar mais uma olhada afora no Google, obrigado pela dica @Lollipop

Comment: Bons estudos!!!